# font-family-Roboto, "Roboto Lt" don't work in iphone 5s

Tags: css, iphone, safari

I use css property font-family,set the value Roboto, "Roboto Lt".
When i use android mobile to browse the pages,font-family is work , but this is not work in iphone 5s browsing the pages through the Safari browser.

Does anybody have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Roboto is included with Android but is not a font included on iOS. You'll need to include the font with Google Fonts.

Comment: then how can i include the font on iOS?use the inline google font,in the head tag??

Comment: Yupp. That's the best way to do it.

Comment: hi,jordans.I have inlcude the font by code:<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> ,just as  google example,but it still not work in iphone 5s.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this answer can help someone else who met this problem as i met.
Here is my resolution, you can do as the steps.

- **Step1:** At first , please access this link
  [ http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto ] to download the zipped
  file. You should choose the Tab Webfont Kit , then click the download
  button "Download @font-face Kit" to download the zipped font file.
- **Step2:** After step1, you must unzipped the downloaded zipped
  file,choose the unzipped your files to the current directory.So you
  will see the directory's name is web fonts, you can open this
  directory and you should see there are so many directories such as
  "roboto_black_macroman ....." and so on.Their names are beginned by
  'roboto',every diretory represent one style of roboto font.You can
  choose one of them you need upload to your website server directory
  as your wish.
- **Step3:** After step2, you should add these codes as under to your css
  style file.Note,you should give the correct path of your font files.**

  ```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('fonts/roboto_regular_macroman/Roboto-Regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/roboto_regular_macroman/Roboto-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/roboto_regular_macroman/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/roboto_regular_macroman/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/roboto_regular_macroman/Roboto-Regular-webfont.svg#RobotoRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  ```

  }

After all, you can directly use the font in use webpage,just as this.
body{font-family:'Roboto',san serif;}

Okay , if you can not figure out what I am trying to say, you can see the original page at this link: http://www.maketecheasier.com/use-google-roboto-font-everywhere/.